# Redirect After Login for each role create with Shinobi Package Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have a question, i want to redirect users to diferent pages after login based in the role, if is admin redirect to admin/users if is normal redirect to admin/norma for example i have the next files

**LoginController.php**

```
    <?php

     namespace App\Admin\Http\Controllers\Auth;

     use App\Admin\Http\Controllers\Controller;
     use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
     use Illuminate\Http\Request;

     class LoginController extends Controller
     {
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Login Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
| redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
| to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
|
*/

use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */

protected $redirectTo = 'admin/users';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}

/**
 * Validate the user login request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return void
 */
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->username() => 'required', 'password' => 'required', //'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|recaptcha',
    ]);
}

}
```

And i use Laravel 5.3 and the Shinobi Package for roles and permissions https://github.com/caffeinated/shinobi

I already create 4 roles in the system database table roles - Administrador/Free/Gold/Diamond

I thinks is something how this

```
    if($user->rol = 'Administrador){
       protected $redirectTo = 'admin/users';
    }else{
       protected $redirectTo = 'admin/normal';
    }
```

But i dont know how exactly make to work, thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the `authenticated` method override. Larvel calls this method after successful login to perform additional checks. You even get the user object and request object. You can perform the user role check and set the redirect path accordingly.

Add this to your `LoginController`

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($user->role == 'admin') {
        $this->redirectTo = 'admin/dashboard';
    } else {
        $this->redirectTo = 'user/dashboard';
    }
}
```

Edit : Since you're using the shinobi package. You need to do the role check like so

```
if ($user->isRole('admin')) {
}
```

Comment: This works in a certain way, but always redirect to user/dashboard i not have role in the $user properties and atribbutes, i print with dd($user), the roles are a diferent table and have a pivot table with name role_user and that is the relation but i dont know how to access to the role, i think that tables are generate for shinobi, regards.

Comment: @AlanCordova there's only so much a person can help you with. You need to take some effort and try to get it done. The answer i gave you clearly answers your question. Incase you need further help with access roles, create a new question. If you really need full help, update your original question or create a new question and i'll look into the shinobi package and help.

Comment: I already solve thanks for your help i will publish the answer

Comment: @AlanCordova anyway i just checked the package and posted the role check method for you. You need to pass the role slug to verify.

Answer (score 0):

I already solve my question in base to shinobi roles and the help of Sandeesh

I add this to my **loginController.php**

```
use Caffeinated\Shinobi\Models\Role;
use Caffeinated\Shinobi\Models\Permission;
```

and the function authenticated is now

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if( $user->isRole( 'administrador' ) ) {
        $this->redirectTo = 'admin/dashboard';
    } else {
        $this->redirectTo = 'user/dashboard';
    }
}
```

And now is working thanks for all :D

Comment: You already get the user object in method parameter, just use that. `$user->isRole('administrator')`

Comment: Yes jajaja my mistake